# Unable to import Flask without virtual enviroment

Tags: python, virtualenv

So, I have my folder, inside it when I create my venv I can use Flask just fine inside my folder.

However, when I start a new project, I do not have a venv yet. I create my server.py file, and I try to "from flask import Flask" but its all grayed out saying:
"Import "flask" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports"

What is the reason for this, and why do I always need to create a venv for flask to work in my folder? I think it is supposed to work without a venv.

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEDxK.png)

[Working with venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbuI6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have flask installed globally?

When you're using a virtual environment, your IDE knows which Python binary to use and the available packages installed. It is therefore aware of flask and can provide language assistance + all of the other relevant features.

When you aren't in a virtual environment, your IDE is defaulting to some Python version on your computer that doesn't have flask as an installed package.

> why do I always need to create a venv for flask to work in my folder? I think it is supposed to work without a venv.

As someone who has coded in Python for over 5 years, I highly encourage you to always use a virtual environment. Venvs allow us to avoid installing Python packages globally which could break system tools or other projects.

Comment: Yes when I do a pip list command (I just open the cmd from the search) I see that I have Flask 2.0.2 Installed and when I do a pip install flask command it just tell me that the requirements are already satisfied.

I will try to stick to working with venvs than, but it's still a little strange for me because I thought I installed it globally.

Comment: Check which Python your IDE is using. It's probably different than what you get in your terminal. Nonetheless, virtual environments fix this problem.